# OpenCv code throws segmentation error(core dumped) Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I'm beginner learning opencv from the official documentation http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video

```
import numpy as np        
import cv2    

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)      
while(True):    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It's giving me error `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"` 
Can anyone please tell me Why is that happening and how to resolve that issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: on which line did your program crash?

Comment: I'm dont know how to find that out. All that i got was "segmentation error(core dumped)" nothing else when i run that code.

Comment: Try removing the cap.release() line from your code. 

From the docs: "In C API, when you finished working with video, release CvCapture structure with cvReleaseCapture(), or use Ptr<CvCapture> that calls cvReleaseCapture() automatically in the destructor."

This makes me think memory is freed automatically and calling cap.release() deletes something prematurely.

Comment: No use. Giving me same error.

Comment: Add checks to your code: `if(!cap.isOpened()) print 'error'` immediately after `cap.open()`. Also add `if(ret==False) print 'frame missing'`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe its a little late but what "user3154952" says is true, when you are working with the C++ api you don't need to use the release method, it is already in the video capture Destructor.

This is the code i tested and worked fine:

```
import sys
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Update:
i have been messing around with my ps3 eye and i've realized that with that camera you get the segmentation error for using only the destroyAllWindows method, to fix that i replaced the destroyAllWindows method with the release method and worked fine, i don't know exactly why that happened i'm just sharing in case someone get that issue. I hope that was helpful.