# imshow in opencv-python doesn't work

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

Error occurred and the program crashed when I executed `cv2.imshow`.

My code was just

```
import cv2
sscv = cv2.imread('/home/myuser/Pictures/Workspace 1_007.png',0)
cv2.imshow("screenshot image", sscv)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The showed Error is

```
    /home/mallory/workspace/python-autoaction/test/test_xutils.py:11: Warning: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'
      cv2.imshow("screenshot image", sscv)
    /home/mallory/workspace/python-autoaction/test/test_xutils.py:11: Warning: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
      cv2.imshow("screenshot image", sscv)
    /home/mallory/workspace/python-autoaction/test/test_xutils.py:11: Warning: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
      cv2.imshow("screenshot image", sscv)
    /home/mallory/workspace/python-autoaction/test/test_xutils.py:11: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
      cv2.imshow("screenshot image", sscv)
    /home/mallory/workspace/python-autoaction/test/test_xutils.py:11: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
      cv2.imshow("screenshot image", sscv)
    /home/mallory/workspace/python-autoaction/test/test_xutils.py:11: Warning: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplay'
      cv2.imshow("screenshot image", sscv)
    /home/mallory/workspace/python-autoaction/test/test_xutils.py:11: Warning: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
      cv2.imshow("screenshot image", sscv)
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

using

- Ubuntu 14.0.4
- Python 2.7.6
- cv2 2.4.8

What was wrong with that?

Comment: FWIW it works fine using `'3.0.0-dev'` on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I see a similar unresolved  error using ubuntu 14.04 here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100516/opencv-code-throws-segmentation-errorcore-dumped-ubuntu-14-04, that code also works fine for me

Comment: How did you install OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing these dependency again and let me know if problem persists

```
sudo apt-get -qq install libopencv-dev build-essential checkinstall cmake pkg-config yasm libjpeg-dev libjasper-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libdc1394-22-dev libxine-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libv4l-dev python-dev python-numpy libtbb-dev libqt4-dev libgtk2.0-dev libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev x264 v4l-utils ffmpeg cmake qt5-default checkinstall
```

After that just do

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
make -j2
sudo checkinstall
sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'
sudo ldconfig
```